# Trying to set a column not null and add a default constraint in one statement

Tags: database, t-sql

Currently I have a column named CreatedDate in a Shipper table I created. It is nullable. My task is to change the created date to be a required field, not allow nulls, and have a default of GetDate(). This has to be done in a single query... Keep in mind there is no data in my table yet. I've tried the following code and I can't seem to get it to work. This is a homework assignment and I'm only looking for guidance. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
USE Business
ALTER TABLE Shipper 
    ALTER COLUMN CreatedDate date NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT CNDefaultCreatedDate 
    DEFAULT GETDATE() For CreatedDate;
```

Comment: Could you be a little more vague than "can't seem to get it to work"? Does the network reboot? Does it delete the database? Is there an error message that might be helpful?

Comment: I get the error message: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'.

Comment: Now, lacking DDL for the table, shall we guess that you want to `alter` the column, but `add` a new default constraint? Your code doesn't `add`.

Comment: Yes I want to ALTER the column to not allow nulls and ADD a default constraint to that column as well. I tried adding the keyword ADD before my default constraint but that gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different statements, I assume this is SQL Server:

```
--Add the default
ALTER TABLE [Shipper]  --What table
ADD CONSTRAINT [def_createddate] --Give the constraint a name
    DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [CreatedDate]; --default of what for which column

--Set to not allow NULL
ALTER TABLE [Shipper] --What table
ALTER COLUMN [CreatedDate] DATE NOT NULL;  --altering what column and either NULL or NOT NULL
```

Understand adding a default will not update existing data.  I know you mentioned your table does not have data, but in the future the null values must be updated to some value before the ALTER COLUMN NOT NULL is allowed.

Here's reference to the MS documentation [ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

If the column did not already exist you can add it, set it not null and then even update existing rows in one statement:

```
--If Shipper did not already have the column CreatedDate
ALTER TABLE [Shipper] 
ADD [CreatedDate] DATE NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [def_createddate] DEFAULT GETDATE()
WITH VALUE --if column is nullable use this and it will update existing records with the default. It column is NOT NULL this is applied by default.
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume we can't do it in one statement? I'm not sure why but my assignment is asking for it in a single query.

Comment: @ZebWeber two different statements, but you can run them together.  Not sure if that is what they mean.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: @ZebWeber if the column did not already exist you could.  I added to the answer as well so you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
USE Business
ALTER TABLE Shipper 
    ALTER COLUMN CreatedDate date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE();
```